# How to subscribe to a new topic with subscribePattern?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I am using Spark Structured streaming with Kafka and topic been subscribed as pattern:

`option("subscribePattern", "topic.*")`

```
// Subscribe to a pattern
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribePattern", "topic.*")
  .load()
```

Once I start the job and a new topic is listed say `topic.new_topic`, the job automatically doesn't start listening to the new topic and it requires a restart.

Is there a way to automatically subscribe to a new pattern without restarting the job?

Spark: 3.0.0

Comment: Since 3.0.0, consumer caching is available, which may allow us to read data from new topics - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#consumer-caching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior of a KafkaConsumer is to check every 5 minutes if there are new partitions to be consumed. This configuration is set through the [Consumer config](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#metadata.max.age.ms)

> *metadata.max.age.ms*: The period of time in milliseconds after which we force a refresh of metadata even if we haven't seen any partition leadership changes to proactively discover any new brokers or partitions.

According to the Spark + Kafka Integration Guide on [Kafka Specific Configuration](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#metadata.max.age.ms) you can set this configuration by using the prefix `kafka.` as shown below:

```
.option("kafka.metadata.max.age.ms", "1000")
```

Through this setting the newly created topic will be consumed 1 second after its creation.

(Tested with Spark 3.0.0 and Kafka Broker 2.5.0)